# why we can't use large bound as replacement for infinity in mosek?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods, cvxpy, mosek

Here in the documentation (https://docs.mosek.com/latest/pythonfusion/debugging-numerical.html)

we see:

> Never use a very large number as replacement for infinity
> . Instead define the variable or constraint as unbounded from below/above. Similarly, avoid artificial huge bounds if you expect they will not become tight in the optimal solution.

why is that the case?

Comment: This is simply a design choice that existed in Mosek for many years. The optimizer API was designed to use bound keys to indicate the type of bound (lower, upper, both, equals) and the Fusion API follows. It is a matter of convention and the other choice would perhaps be just as good, but it is how it is.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thanks but I just wonder why numerically we'd break with a big upper bound?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. A big number used as a bound (or anywhere else, no difference) enters into all kinds of calculations and affects numerical precision. From this point of view infinity would be even better, because one can find it and eliminate that bound internally, but, like I said, currently boundkeys/domains are used for that and not Inf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is if you have something like

x <= 10^20,

then does 10^20 actually mean infinity or not. So I wanted to force users to carefully consider whether they meant infinity or some finite number. So it is meant as a help to the users. Although I knew they might find it annoying.

If you want a theoretical argument for large bounds are can be bad for computational complexity (=number of iterations), then read Section 5.2 at

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118032701